# SQLでDistinctをExistに置き換えたい

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

検索結果のクエリ速度を上げるため、DistinctをExistに置き換えたいのですが、自分には複雑でうまく置き換えができませんでした。
2つあるのですが、下記となります。
尚、計測したところ合計で約2.5秒ほどかかっています。(wp_postmetaは30万件)

1つ目

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   PM.meta_value AS madorisu,
   PM_2.meta_value AS madorisyurui 
FROM
   (
       (
           (
                wp_posts AS P 
                INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS PM 
                ON P.ID = PM.post_id
           ) 
           INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS PM_1
           ON P.ID = PM_1.post_id
       ) 
       INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS PM_2
       ON P.ID = PM_2.post_id
   )
WHERE
    P.post_status = 'publish' 
AND P.post_password = '' 
AND P.post_type = 'fudo' 
AND PM_1.meta_key = 'bukkenshubetsu' 
AND CAST( PM_1.meta_value AS SIGNED ) > 3000 
AND PM.meta_key = 'madorisu' 
AND PM_2.meta_key = 'madorisyurui'
```

2つ目

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   DTR.rosen_name,
   DTR.rosen_id,
   DTS.station_name,
   DTS.station_id,
   DTS.station_ranking  
FROM
   (
       (
           (
               (
                   (
                       (
                           wp_posts AS P
                        )
                        INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS PM 
                        ON P.ID = PM.post_id
                    )  
                    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS PM_1
                    ON P.ID = PM_1.post_id
                )
                INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS PM_2 
                ON P.ID = PM_2.post_id
            )  
            INNER JOIN wp_train_rosen AS DTR
            ON CAST( PM_1.meta_value AS SIGNED ) = DTR.rosen_id
        )  
        INNER JOIN wp_train_station AS DTS
        ON  DTS.rosen_id = DTR.rosen_id 
        AND CAST( PM.meta_value AS SIGNED ) = DTS.station_id
   )
WHERE
    (
        P.post_status = 'publish'  
        AND P.post_password = ''  
        AND P.post_type = 'fudo'  
        AND PM.meta_key = 'koutsueki1'  
        AND PM_1.meta_key = 'koutsurosen1'  
        AND PM_2.meta_key = 'bukkenshubetsu'  
        AND PM_2.meta_value > 3000 
    )
OR  (
        P.post_status = 'publish'  
        AND P.post_password = ''  
        AND P.post_type = 'fudo'  
        AND PM.meta_key = 'koutsueki2'  
        AND PM_1.meta_key = 'koutsurosen2'  
        AND PM_2.meta_key = 'bukkenshubetsu'  
        AND PM_2.meta_value > 3000 
    )
```

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

post_metaの構造ですが、ワードプレス標準のものをそのまま利用しており下記となっています。

【post_metaテーブル】（１つ目の参考に抜粋しました。meta_idがプライマリとなります。）

| meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| 100000 | 3120 | mardorisu | 4 |
| 100001 | 3120 | mardorisyurui | 10 |

【期待する結果】（１つ目の抜粋）

| mardorisu | mardorisyurui |
| 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 50 |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 55 |
| 3 | 30 |

Comment: 「DistinctをExistに置き換えたい」という意図がよく分かりません。指定条件を満たすレコードが存在するかどうかだけが知りたいということでしょうか？

Comment: テーブル定義と実際の値、期待する結果を書いていただいた方がよろしいかと思います。あとそれぞれのテーブルの行数。サブクエリーを目の敵にしている人もいますが、うまく使って行数を絞ってからJOINすると良いことが多いです。

Comment: テーブル定義的に必ずユニークになるような内容がベースに存在しないとDISTINCTからEXISTSへの書き換えは効果を発揮しません。各テーブルで何がPRIMARY KEYやUNIQUE KEYになっているかがわからないと全く手を出せない書き換えですが、テーブル名(WordPressベース?)や書かれているSQLから推定して、EXISTSへの書き換えがうまくできる可能性はほぼないと言って良いでしょう。他の方のご意見を参考にして、他の方法でのチューニングを考えるべきです。

Comment: WP標準のDBなんですね。[ER図を見つけました](https://codex.wordpress.org/images/2/2a/WP3.9.4-ERD.png)。30万件は小さなDBだと思って良いです。

Answer (score 1):

`Exists` 句の使用は相関副問合せとセットとなる事が多いのですが、そうするとパフォーマンスは悪化する事の方が多いです。それよりも `OR` を避ける事に注力する方が良いプランになるように思います。

ところで、インデックスは使用されているでしょうか。

> (wp_postmetaは30万件)

との事でネックは `wp_postmeta` の方だと思いますので、`wp_postmeta` に `post_id` 及び `meta_key` のカバリングインデックスを作成するとクエリパフォーマンスの向上が見込めると思います。

Comment: Inasyncさん、ありがとうございます。
インデックスの設定などは行っていませんでした。
wp_postmetaにpost_idのカバリングインデックスとは、post_id,meta_id,meta_key,meta_valueをグループ化したインデックスを作るということであっていますか？
上記とmeta_keyも同様に行ったのですが、パフォーマンスがまったく改善されませんでした。
もう少し詳しく教えていただければ幸いです。

Comment: `CREATE INDEX ix_wp_postmeta ON wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key)` のようなインデックスをイメージしていましたが、パフォーマンス向上には寄与しませんでしたか。。。きちんとクエリチューニングするとなると `EXPLAIN` でクエリプランを見る必要がありますね。[【MySQL】遅いselect文の原因を調査する【explainの読み方】 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/mtanabe/items/33a80bf2749a872645e6) 等の記事を参考に試してみて下さい。

Comment: Inasyncさん、ありがとうございます。
インデックスの設定ですが、下記にて2.5秒⇒1.2秒まで縮めることができました。

CREATE INDEX `IX-wp_postmeta-post_id-meta_key-meta_value`
    ON `wp_postmeta` (`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`);

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26319613/improving-a-query-using-a-lot-of-inner-joins-to-wp-postmeta-a-key-value-table)

Answer (score 0):

*返信をいただいたので回答を更新。*

## ver 0.2

想定条件: meta_key madorisyuruiとmadorisuはpost一つにつきそれぞれ一度しか現れない。publishされているpostが全体のうち大半を占める。

ポイントとしては
1. 質問者の元のクエリではwp_posts x wp_postmeta x wp_postmeta x wp_postmetaとなって行数が爆発するから、先にサブSELECTで、wp_postmetaを一度だけ読み込んでbukkenshubetsuの条件に従ってmadirisyurui,madorisuだけ抽出した。
2. ほとんどのpostsはpublishされているので上で抽出した行で捨てるものはほとんど無い想定。もし想定が逆なら先にpost_idでメタデータのSELECTを絞ることも考えると良い。
3. group_concatしているのは縦のテーブルを横のテーブルに変換するため。

```
select
        pm3.madorisyurui,
        pm3.madorisu
from
        wp_posts as p join
        (
        select
                pm2.post_id as post_id,
                group_concat(case when meta_key='madorisyurui' then meta_value end) as madorisyurui,
                group_concat(case when meta_key='madorisu' then meta_value end) as madorisu
        from
                wp_postmeta as pm2 join
                (
                select
                        post_id
                from
                        wp_postmeta
                where
                        meta_key='bukkenshubetsu' AND
                        CAST( meta_value AS SIGNED ) > 3000
                ) as pm1
                ON pm1.post_id=pm2.post_id
        where
                meta_key in ('madorisyurui', 'madorisu')
        group by 1
        ) as pm3
        ON (
           p.id = pm3.post_id and
           p.post_status = 'publish' and
           p.post_password = '' AND
           p.post_type = 'fudo'
           )
group by 1,2
;
```

## ver 0.1

最適なクエリーはデータの行数、性質によりますし、検証のしようがないので、目的にあっているのかもわかりませんが、とりあえずの回答です。目的に合わない、速度が遅いと言うことであればご指摘ください。返信があればその2についても考えてみます。

```
select
        p.id,
        group_concat(case when pm3.meta_key='madorisyurui' then pm3.meta_value end order by 1) as madorisyurui,
        group_concat(case when pm3.meta_key='madorisu' then pm3.meta_value end order by 1) as madorisu
from
        wp_posts as p join
        (
        select
                pm2.post_id as post_id,
                meta_key,
                meta_value
        from
                wp_postmeta as pm2 join
                (
                select
                        post_id
                from
                        wp_postmeta
                where
                        meta_key='bukkenshubetsu' AND
                        CAST( meta_value AS SIGNED ) > 3000
                ) as pm1
                ON pm1.post_id=pm2.post_id
        where
                meta_key in ('madorisyurui', 'madorisu')
        ) as pm3
        ON (
           p.id = pm3.post_id and
           p.post_status = 'publish' and
           p.post_password = '' AND
           p.post_type = 'fudo'
           )
group by p.id
;
```

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。パフォーマンスとしては0.5s⇒0.04sになり十分な効果が見込めました。

Comment: Kenjiさん、ありがとうございます。
post_metaの構造ですが、ワードプレス標準のものをそのまま利用しており下記となっています。

【post_metaテーブル】
`meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
100000 | 3120 | mardorisu | 4 |
100001 | 3120 | mardorisyurui | 10 |`


【期待する結果】
`| mardorisu | mardorisyurui |
| 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 50 |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 55 |
| 3 | 30 |`


クエリをテストしたところ期待したものと異なっていました。
p.idで、グループ化されていたことが原因のようだったので、そこをmadorisuでグループすると下記のようになってしまいました。
`| mardorisyurui | madorisu |
| 10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10... | 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,..|`

引き続きよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: meta_key madorisyuruiとmadorisuはpost一つにつきそれぞれ一度しか現れないと言う想定でいいでしょうか？

Comment: kenjiさん、ご連絡が遅くなり申し訳ありません。
「meta_key madorisyuruiとmadorisuはpost一つにつきそれぞれ一度しか現れないと言う想定でいいでしょうか？」
⇒はい、そのとおりです！

Answer (score -1):

別回答の形で恐縮です。
質問者さんのクエリの要件を明確にしたかったのでクエリを整形してみたのですが、この認識で相違ないでしょうか？

1)

```
-- 記事に紐づく、`madorisu` と `madorisyurui` の組合せ一覧
SELECT DISTINCT
   madorisu.meta_value AS madorisu,
   madorisyurui.meta_value AS madorisyurui 
FROM wp_posts AS post 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS bukkenshubetsu ON post.ID = bukkenshubetsu.post_id AND bukkenshubetsu.meta_key = 'bukkenshubetsu'
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS madorisu       ON post.ID = madorisu.post_id AND madorisu.meta_key = 'madorisu' 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS madorisyurui   ON post.ID = madorisyurui.post_id AND madorisyurui.meta_key = 'madorisyurui'
WHERE
    post.post_status = 'publish' 
AND post.post_password = '' 
AND post.post_type = 'fudo' 
AND CAST(bukkenshubetsu.meta_value AS SIGNED) > 3000
```

2)

```
-- 記事に紐づく、`路線`と`駅`の組合せ一覧
SELECT 
   rosen.rosen_name,
   rosen.rosen_id,
   station.station_name,
   station.station_id,
   station.station_ranking  
FROM (
    -- 先に rosen_id と station_id の組合せで一意に絞り込む。
    SELECT DISTINCT
        CAST(koutsurosen.meta_value AS SIGNED) AS rosen_id,
        CAST(koutsueki.meta_value AS SIGNED) AS station_id
    FROM wp_posts AS post
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS bukkenshubetsu ON post.ID = bukkenshubetsu.post_id AND bukkenshubetsu.meta_key = 'bukkenshubetsu'
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS koutsueki      ON post.ID = koutsueki.post_id
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS koutsurosen    ON post.ID = koutsurosen.post_id
    WHERE
        post.post_status = 'publish'  
    AND post.post_password = ''  
    AND post.post_type = 'fudo'  
    AND bukkenshubetsu.meta_value > 3000
    AND (
        koutsueki.meta_key = 'koutsueki1' AND koutsurosen.meta_key = 'koutsurosen1'  
        OR
        koutsueki.meta_key = 'koutsueki2' AND koutsurosen.meta_key = 'koutsurosen2'
    )
) t
INNER JOIN wp_train_rosen AS rosen     ON t.rosen_id = rosen.rosen_id
INNER JOIN wp_train_station AS station ON t.station_id = station.station_id AND rosen.rosen_id = station.rosen_id
```